# How to search for a setting inside Atom package settings?

Tags: atom-editor

Using Github's `Atom`, I installed the `atom-beautify` package.
This package has **hundreds** of lines of configurable settings.

My expectation was that hitting `CMD + F` would allow me to search for a string within these settings (e.g. `CSS - Indent` should find that setting - I am currently getting `No results found...`).

However, the find box that opens does nothing.

To clarify, I'm not asking [how to `Filter packages by name`](https://github.com/atom/settings-view/issues/394) from the `Packages` view; I'm asking how to search for specific settings within a package settings page.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The nuclide package implemented their own settings page, which includes the ability to search for settings.  It's really nice, but specific to nuclide.  I wish Atom had this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the issue [#394](https://github.com/atom/settings-view/issues/394) (and other referenced issues) seems like it is impossible to look for any setting in the Atom settings view.

I suggest you to configure the package with a configuration file using the following documentation - https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/blob/master/docs/options.md.

Comment: Thanks. What a weird option not to have. Maybe I'll hack it together and create a pull request.